# SpringBoot + Docker

Tags: spring, docker

Всем привет! Изучаю docker. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста кто занет. Нужно создать образ для веб-приложения которое использует бд postgres. Приложение разбито на модули. Модуль бд отдельно и веб отдельно. Создать образ для веб получилось но при запуске  падает естественно ошибка что не найденна бд. Как можно решить данную ситуацию, кто расскажет, кто подскажет?

Comment: По Вашему вопросу трудно что нибудь ответить. Конкретизируйте пожалуйста вопрос. Запускаете ли Вы образы через `docker-compose` или делаете по другому? Если через `docker-compose` покажите `docker-compose.yml` файл. Чем развернуто и правильно зададите вопрос, тем точнее будет ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял вашего вопроса, но посмотрите в сторону Bridge network в докере, вам нужно линкануть один контейнер у другому, гляньте man по команде docker run

Answer (score 0):

Из описания непонятно, запускается БД в том же контейнере или нет. В любом случае, по-умолчанию все порты контейнера закрыты, и вам нужно явно их открывать через -p. Кроме того, внутреннее взаимодействие между контейнерами в рамках одной машины тоже нужно настраивать